How can I increase process noice to account for large changes of acceleration during my vehicles flight?
I am developing a loosely-coupled GNSS/INS with a discrete EKF navigator for a 6-DOF missile model in Simulink. Currently, my position, velocity, attitude, and bias errors are within my 3-sigma bounds until the acceleration profile changes drastically. How can I account for these changes in my filter.

It seems you want to implement a robust Kalman filter that can deal with outliers. See here for an example of how to implement one using cvxpy (this can be implemented using CVX in MATLAB).
